# loopback using arduino to check LAN port connectivity

Tags: arduino

is there any way that I can use Arduino to send data to the LAN port (oscilloscope) to see the link and activity light but without using internet.. or maybe some programming that related to loopback. This is because the loopback cable that I've made are not working on the oscilloscope and only works on the pc.

Btw, I'm not using the LAN cable that connects between the wall and oscilloscope to avoid any virus. If possible I would like a solution that does not use any connection to the internet but can make the green and amber light at the LAN port to light up.

Comment: Does the Arduino have a Ethernet port?

Comment: For now, I only have arduino uno.

Comment: What do you mean by a "loopback cable"? Are you confusing that with a crossover cable?

Comment: `I'm not using the LAN cable that connects between the wall and oscilloscope to avoid any virus.` ... you are not using the cable for what? ... avoid viruses in what?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a network hub or switch that is not connected to anything else.  You will get a link and be able to see the activity lights if you send anything.

Comment: okay thanks.. But, may i know can the switch lights up both light (green and amber)?

Comment: It will establish the link, and you will be able to send data.  There is no single standard for what the two LEDs do, so you'll have to let us know what ethernet controller/board you are using on the arduino.  If you are using GPIO's directly and trying to establish an ethernet connection you should give up and use a chip based ethernet solution.  In general your question is vague and needs more information to get useful answers.